# What is compared in a model comparison?

Tags: regression, interaction, model-comparison

What is the purpose of model comparison? Is it to make the same predictions about the response variable, using the same regression formula of predictor variables, but with varying specifications (like transformed or not data, different probability distributions) in order to see what assumptions give the best fit? Or is the purpose to test varying regression formulas (changing interaction terms, or fixed /random intercepts etc.) to investigate what research hypothesis gives the best fit? Does it make sense to compare models that differ in both ways, that is have different model assumptions and also different formulation?

I am trying to understand what models to generate in order to compare to the one I believe is the most valid.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Might I suggest editing your post to ask a specific question concerning your modeling situation?  This collection of questions is just a little too vague and general to be suitable here -- and you can find out a great deal about them just by [searching our site.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=model+comparison)

Comment: Model comparison takes many flavors and the question can't be answered as-is: you can compare models to assess statistical significance of (a) variable(s), to assess predictiveness, to enforce parsimony, to assess a complexity/predictiveness tradeoff, etc. Models come from different data, the same data, or subsets of the same dataset.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I realize this was too vague, and will try to be more specific next time.